Search a pattern and replace next line with another pattern in Shell script
I have comma seperated file with 3 values. I want to find pattern1 , and in next line I have value 2 , which needs tobe replaced with Value 3.
eg. File
XXX,YYY,ZZZ
AAA,BBB,CCC

I need to compare XXX; when matched in next line I have YYY, which needs to replace with ZZZ
What is the sed for this ?
trid sed command with \n operation for next line, but struggling

You have YYY in the same line as XXX, not the next line. Can you fix the example?

Is this supposed to be case-insensitive?

You're not allowed to change your question into a different one in a way that invalidates the answers you already received. I have rolled back your change (though unhappily, that now invalidates an answer which was updated after your change). Ask a new question with your actual requirements up front.

Your edit to the question significantly changed it; originally it looked like you wanted to change values in a CSV file. Now it looks like you want to use that CSV file to direct changes to another file. You really should have included that detail originally instead of making people waste time with answers to something that isn't your real question.
Anyways... here's one way, using the under-appreciated ed editor to make the changes all in one go:
(
    # for each line of ref.txt, split up on commas
    while IFS=, read -r marker from to; do
        # For each line of test.txt that matches the first field,
        # substitute the second field with the third on the next line
        printf "g/%s/+1s/%s/%s/\n" "$marker" "$from" "$to"
    done < ref.txt
    echo w # save changes
    echo q # quit ed
) | ed -s test.txt

After running this command, test.txt now looks like:
[tst]
Database=xxx
HostName=zzz

[tst1]
Database=aaa
HostName=ccc

(I lowercased your example ref.txt file before running this).

The OP shouldn't have changed their question. I rolled back their edit, which however rendered this answer partially out of sync with the question. It's unclear how  you would like to adapt, if at all, so I haven't changed your answer. Maybe it's moot now anyway. Going forward, if this happens again, probably flag the question for mod attention rather than update your answer. Again, sorry for the wasted effort on all sides.

Is there a flag for ignore case ("I") , if pattern is not mix of upper/lower case

Use awk. When you match the search pattern, use getline to go to the next line in the input, and perform the substitution.
awk '/XXX/ { print; getline; sub("YYY", "ZZZ"); print}'


Didnt generate output as desired. Can you suggest ?

Can you please update the question with sample input and the desired output?

You can achieve this using sed with the following command:sed -r '/XXX/ { n; s/YYYY/ZZZ/ }' file.txt
Here's how it works:

'/XXX/' searches for the pattern 'XXX'.
'{ n; ... }' executes the commands inside the block when the pattern is found. 'n'moves to the next line.
's/YYYY/ZZZ/'replaces 'YYY' with 'ZZZ' on the next line.

Note: The -r option enables extended regular expressions, which allows you to use parentheses without escaping them.
If you want to modify the original file, add the -i option:
sed -ri '/XXX/ { n; s/YYYY/ZZZ/ }' file.txt

This will replace the original file with the modified output.

-E is another common (and in the newest POSIX standard) option to use extended REs.

And some sed implementations that take -i have a mandatory argument to it, others optional.

No luck with it. I updated a sample code, if you can review ?
